# What can be used instead of tree.dataProvider in adobe flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have my .mxml as below:

```
  <fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XMLList id="data">
        <node>
            <node label="Inbox">
                <node label="Marketing"/>
                <node label="Product Management"/>
                <node label="Personal"/>
            </node>
            <node label="Outbox">
                <node label="Professional"/>
                <node label="Private"/>
            </node>
            <node label="Spam">kushal</node>
            <node label="Sent"/>
        </node>
    </fx:XMLList>
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:VBox>
    <mx:Button label="Search by name" click="findByName()" />  

    <mx:Tree id="tree" width="500" height="500" 
             showRoot="false" dataProvider="{data}" 
             labelField="@label" />
</mx:VBox>
```

I'm trying to click     findByName()  on click of a button:
which is:

```
private function findByName():void
    {



        var mixml:XMLList = new XMLList(data);



        var searchStr:String = "Outbox";
        //child.expandChildrenOf(myXML[0], false);




        //mixml=data;

        searchResult= mixml.node.(@label==searchStr);



        var xn:XML = searchResult[searchResultIndex];
        Alert.show("xn"+ xn);


            searchResultIndex = 0;
        if (searchResult[searchResultIndex] != undefined)


            var xmlNode:XML = searchResult[searchResultIndex];

        while (xmlNode.parent() != null) {


            Alert.show("xmlNodeBefore"+ xmlNode);
            xmlNode = xmlNode.parent();

            Alert.show("xmlNodeAfter"+ xmlNode);

            //checkpoint 1

            tree.expandItem(xmlNode, true, false);
            tree.selectedItem = searchResult[searchResultIndex];

            Alert.show(" tree.selectedItem " + tree.selectedItem );
        }
    }
```

If here instead of    data
I use      tree.dataProvider then this code doesn't work, can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Please see my answer below and let me know if it works for you! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mate!! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad to help! Thanks for accepting the answer. Some how I did not recieve the bounty? Can you please award it? Thanks

Comment: Yeah shortly, there was a time limit of an hour before I could award it :P

Comment: Oh thanks. Did not know it worked that way! Anyways, pleasure to help out. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work when you use `tree.dataProvider` because it's of the type `XMLListCollection`, which is a wrapper on top of the `XMLList` object. Flex internally transforms the `XMLList` into a `XMLListCollection`, because `XMLListCollection` has capabilities of providing change notifications via events, which `XMLList` does not.

So in your code, if you use `tree.dataProvider` at the following line :

```
var mixml:XMLList = new XMLList(tree.dataProvider);
```

You are actually trying to type cast and convert an `XMLListCollection` into a XMLList, which is why it does not work.

Interestingly, the `XMLListCollection` has public properties (like most collections in Flex) which can be used to access the underlying `XMLList` source from which it is made up of. So, to access the data from the tree, one correct way would be:

```
var mixml:XMLList = new XMLList(tree.dataProvider.source);
```

I have tried this in your code and it seems to do the same job as your above code.

You can read more about this here :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/XMLListCollection.html#source

Hope this explanation works and it answers your question overall.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the setter for Tree.dataProvider you can see that it modifies/translates the value that get's passed in.

This line of code will cast to null because dataProvider changes xml based data into XmlListCollection.

```
var mixml:XMLList = new XMLList(data);
```

Here is the setter for reference.

```
override public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void
{
    // in all cases save off the original
    if (_rootModel)
        _rootModel.removeEventListener(
                        CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, 
                        collectionChangeHandler);

    // handle strings and xml
    if (typeof(value)=="string")
        value = new XML(value);
    else if (value is XMLNode)
        value = new XML(XMLNode(value).toString());
    else if (value is XMLList)
        value = new XMLListCollection(value as XMLList);

    if (value is XML)
    {
        _hasRoot = true;
        var xl:XMLList = new XMLList();
        xl += value;
        _rootModel = new XMLListCollection(xl);
    }
    //if already a collection dont make new one
    else if (value is ICollectionView)
    {
        _rootModel = ICollectionView(value);
        if (_rootModel.length == 1)
            _hasRoot = true;
    }
    else if (value is Array)
    {
        _rootModel = new ArrayCollection(value as Array);
    }
    //all other types get wrapped in an ArrayCollection
    else if (value is Object)
    {
        _hasRoot = true;
        // convert to an array containing this one item
        var tmp:Array = [];
        tmp.push(value);
        _rootModel = new ArrayCollection(tmp);
    }
    else
    {
        _rootModel = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    //flag for processing in commitProps
    dataProviderChanged = true;
    invalidateProperties();
}
```

Comment: sorry I wasn't more clear… data get's morphed into XMLListCollection I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Then what do i use instead of tree.dataProvider?

Comment: use data directly

Comment: I can't for my purpose. I need an alternative

Comment: create a subclass of tree and override set dataProvider

Comment: I have a question that my code output is exactly the same until 'checkpoint 1' whether I use 'data' or 'tree.dataProvider', only the later part is not working. Could you help me understand why because the solution you provided is bit difficult for me to replicate.